# Build legend in CartoDB using createLayer

Tags: carto

I'm not using `createVis`, but rather `createLayer` to generate my maps on the fly, but can't seem to figure out how to add a legend using something simple like `legends: true`, which is available when using `createVis`.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually add Legends to the map using the objects in cdb.geo.ui.Legend

```
var densityLegend = new cdb.geo.ui.Legend.Density({
            title:   "<a href='http://www.fbi.gov/about-us/cjis/ucr/ucr'>Data From FBI Crime Reporting 2013</a>",
            left: "Low", right: "High", colors: [ "#FFFFB2", "#FED976", "#FEB24C", "#FD8D3C", "#FC4E2A", "#E31A1C", "#B10026"  ]
        });
        $('#map').append(densityLegend.render().el);
```

An example of doing this for a density legend is given [here](http://blog.cartodb.com/layer-selector/).

Comment: Thanks...this worked, but I don't know why. I can't find any documentation for `Legend` anywhere. It seems like there are different kinds (density, bubble), but I have no idea where to read up more on this. Any ideas?